# Determining Documents folder redirection on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a desktop winforms application, I am using the Documents folder to store user data. Some users have redirected this folder to a server location. In Windows 7, I can successfully detect this using:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

In Windows 8 (specifically 8.1 Update 1), this results in a "\" response when the folder in redirected. It works correctly if it is not redirected.

I need to determine where this redirection is going to in order to access the user data.

Comment: Is this of any help? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814354/environment-specialfolder-mydocuments-has-been-broken-under-windows-8-1-now-points-to-skydrive

Comment: @RenniePet, thanks for the link - unfortunately that does not show any resolution to the issue or even for Microsoft on how to reproduce it. I will see if there are any other comments and if not, submit something to Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

The issue is actually related to rights.

Visual Studio is running as Administrator, if you run an admin command prompt and type in net use there are no mapped drives. A normal command prompt returns the mapped drives.

By enabling linked locations in the registry as per this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx) it now returns the value in Visual Studio.